# Getting Null value In the logcat

Tags: java, android, constructor

I am in my learning phase. I don't know why am I getting Null value in logcat. When getN() is called it first constructor, it shows result but when called in the 2nd constructor, it shows Null value. Please, can anyone explain me this or point me to an article so I can read in detail about this.

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String G = "HELLo";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MyActivity s = new MyActivity(G);
    MyActivity my = new MyActivity();
}
}
```

**MyActivity.class**

```
public class MyActivity {
String N;

public MyActivity(String g) {
    this.N = g;
}

public MyActivity() {
    getN();
}


public void getN(){
    Log.e("WOFO",N);
}
}
```

Comment: When you call it in the second constructor, you never initialize `N`, so it still has a value of `null`.

Comment: @azurefrog  Oh now I get it, But Is there any way I can get this String G value In String N.

Comment: If you want to initialize your object with that string, why not just use the constructor that accepts a string and initializes itself with it?

Answer (score 0):

when you are calling `MyActivity s = new MyActivity(G);` you initialize `N` with `this.N = g;` but at the second call the `this.N = g;` is not initialized because you are calling a new instance of the object not the same as the first one.

Comment: Ohk now I get it, But Is there any way I can get this String G value In String N.